# Why do turkey bacon slices form bubbles in the same places?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, bubbles, food

Often, turkey bacon forms large bubbles when cooking. It's simply a fact of how it cooks. More interestingly however, I was making turkey bacon this morning when I noticed that all of the slices formed bubbles in nearly exactly the same place along the slice, regardless of where on the pan the bacon was situated. What would account for this?

[image: Turkey bacon showing bubble formation]

What structural details of the turkey would cause the slices to form bubbles in the same place?

Comment: Can you attach a picture?

Comment: @knzhou Yep, done. You can see three large bubbles in the meat of each of the slices above, one small bubble to the left, and large bubbles in the middle and to the right

Comment: Oh, then I would guess it's just because of the distribution of fat, which is roughly similar in each one (for biological reasons). The fat shrinks during cooking which determines the shape.

Comment: Well, IF you really want to seriously investigate this, then you need to do a systematic study and then present all of your data. You'll need to check for reproducibility of the phenomenon (your picture only shows two slices which look similar). Also, you'll need to see if the same pattern of bubbles persists throughout the entire pack of turkey bacon slices from one end of the pack to the other. Also, are there any similarities to bubble patterns shown by completely different packs of turkey bacon?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Sounds like I'm in for some research then :) I'll keep this question open in case someone else has already looked into this and stumbles upon it, but I've never had a good excuse to write a paper about bacon before

Comment: There's always the *IgNobel Prizes* to work for.

Answer (score 2):

this product is probably extruded from a mixer/grinder and then sliced thinly across the extrusion direction. This makes each slice cook up similarly because the distribution of ingredients in any two slices will be similar.

there was a time when the safeway store chain sold pre-sliced swiss cheese in plastic packaging. the location of the holes in each slice was similar, and when I found a slice which still had the punched-out round of swiss still sitting in the center of the slice, the light bulb went on.

it's all "food science".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a trick of perspective, but it seems to me that it is an effect due to the fact that the bacon is bulging outwards in some parts (the pink-ish ones), and therefore the fat/water mixture that comes out because of the heat slides downwards, and then partly evaporates forming bubbles.

The bulging may be due to the fact that low fat (pink-ish) and high-fat (withe-ish) regions of the meat deform in different ways when their temperature is raised, but I have no idea about the physical mechanism behind this phenomenon...